# How can Perl detect a file if I don't know the exact filepath?

Tags: regex, linux, perl, search, path

I am trying to search for a file under specific path/location.

```
Sample Path - /var/log/<parent1>/<parent2>/<folder>/file
```

Now, there are two directories `<parent1>` and `<parent2>` as show in sample path. These two directories have some random name so their names can not be predicted. Except these two directory names, every part of path is known.

I tried doing something like this --

```
if ( -e $filePath ) {
    # Do something here
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work. So, how can search for the specific file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a file glob:

`</var/log/*/*/folder/file>`

This does the same thing the shell does with a similar pattern.

Or you can use the `glob` function.  [`perldoc -f glob`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html) for details.